# How to concat a specific value from a object and a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function below as to be re-usable.

```
function fnGetRowData(DataTableID, rowData) {
var row = $("#" + DataTableID).find(".dtactive");
var data = $("#" + DataTableID).DataTable().row(row[0]).data();
var ret = data + "" + rowData;

return ret;
}
```

**var data value**

.FirstName

.MidName

.LastName

> Expected Output: I want to get the data of data.FirstName (eg. John)

but the `ret` console return is `[object Object]` when i try the code above `data + "." + rowData`. The concat output is like this `[object Object].FirstName"`

How can i get the value of the FirstName?. Is it possible or no?

Thanks.

Comment: you have to segregate the object. what will be the expected result of `var data`?

Comment: Ow sorry I forgot the expected output.. I'll update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following line. I guess it will solve your problem.

```
var ret = data[rowData];
```

Comment: You save my life.. Thanks a lot.